# Console Status Bar

Tags: c#

I have a function that would update the status bar in a console application with the following  statement:

```
Console.writeline("Status {0} Copied", i);
```

The problem with the above statement is that after a while, it would fill up the console line with statements stating:

```
Status 1 Copied
Status 2 Copied
```

etc etc.

Is there a way to have it only refresh one line so that the 1 would be replaced by 2 and so on so it doesn't end up  with a wall of text?

Comment: guess ur writeline is in any loop?

Comment: Its not possible to edit any logged message in console.  I prefer you use some label, and change the text of the label if you are using winforms.

Comment: I don't believe so.  I think it's simply `stdout` and so just appends to what's there.  I guess you could try something funky with ASCII special characters for backspace, but I wouldn't put money on it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To repeatedly write the output at the start of the *current* line, try:

```
private static void SetStatusLineValue(int value)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.Write("\rStatus {0} Copied", value);
}
```

Or even simply: `Console.Write("\rStatus {0} Copied", value);`

For a more flexible solution which either 'remembers' the start line, or uses a nominated line:

```
private static void SetTextForLine(string text, ref int line)
{
    //set the status line for future reference
    if (line < 0)
    {
        line = Console.CursorTop;
    }

    //save line/cursor state
    int currentLine = Console.CursorTop;
    bool cursorVisible = Console.CursorVisible;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, line);
    Console.WriteLine(text);

    //restore state
    Console.CursorTop = (currentLine == line ? currentLine + 1 : currentLine);
    Console.CursorVisible = cursorVisible;
}
```

Usage:

```
int statusLine = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Other lines in here...");

    DoLongRunningOperation();

    //update the status line here
    SetTextForLine("Status " + i + " Copied", ref statusLine);
}
```

Output:

```
Other lines in here...
Status 9 Copied            <- this line updating each SetTextForLine() call
Other lines in here...
Other lines in here...
Other lines in here...
Other lines in here...
Other lines in here...
Other lines in here...
Other lines in here...
Other lines in here...
Other lines in here...
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's completely possible, you just need to keep track of which line you are on and then overwrite that:

```
   Console.Write("0000000000");
   Console.SetCursorPosition(3, 0);
   Console.Write("55");
   Console.ReadLine();
```

OUTPUT: 005500000

```
Console.WriteLine("0000000000");
Console.WriteLine("1111111111");
Console.WriteLine("2222222222");

Console.SetCursorPosition(3, 1);
Console.Write("55");
Console.ReadLine();
```

OUTPUT:

0000000000

1155111111

2222222222

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the method **Console.MoveBufferArea** to scroll the console output.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.SetBufferSize(Console.WindowWidth, Console.WindowHeight);

  Console.CursorLeft = 0;
  Console.CursorTop = 0;

  Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
  Console.Write("This is the statusbar".PadRight(Console.WindowWidth, ' '));

  Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

  int line = 1;
  int totalLines = 1;
  while (true) {
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    if (line == Console.WindowHeight){
      // Scoll one line:
      Console.MoveBufferArea(0, 2, Console.WindowWidth, Console.WindowHeight - 2, 0, 1);
      line--;
    }
    Console.CursorLeft = 0;
    Console.CursorTop = line;
    Console.Write(string.Format("This is line {0}", totalLines));

    totalLines++;
    line++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible ways to do that but you can try one solution to clear out the console screen before the next message will be written.

```
Console.Clear();
```

Another one you can try: `"\r"` to go back to the beginning of the current line and re-write the text.

```
Console.Write("\rStatus {0} copied", i);
```

Else you can go with [WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: this won's solve the case when he uses `WriteLine`, setting cursor position should be considered instead.

Comment: It is possible. Setting the cursor position is a solution other than clearing the screen.

Comment: As rhughes said, definitely possible, methods are the foundations for building simpler terminal hosted UI's.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted the answer because it has helped me in producing the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Before Output");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
          int currentLine = Console.CursorTop;
          Console.WriteLine("i is {0}", i);
          Thread.Sleep(500);
          Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLine);
     }
Console.WriteLine("After");
```

This is the code that I am going to be using.